# Table rows into columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, multiple-columns, rows

Say I have a database similar to the following:

Table events_degree:

```
event_id     degree_id
    1           1
    1           31
  ...           ...
```

Table events_area:

```
event_id     area_id
    1           1
    1           31
  ...           ...
```

Table events_schedule:

```
event_id     schedule
    1          Time 1
    1          Time 2
  ...           ...
```

Table events:

```
   id           name
    1           prom
    2         homecoming
  ...           ...
```

Table degree:

```
    id          name           shortened
    1     computer science        cs
    2      something else         se
  ...           ...              ...
```

Table area:

```
    id          name
    1           hall 1
    2            gym
  ...           ...
```

Table building:

```
    id          name
    1         main building
    2        second building
  ...           ...
```

What i want to do it's merge the columns since i have this query

```
SELECT `e`.*, `eh`.`start_date`, `eh`.`end_date`, `c`.`name` AS `degree_name`, `c`.`shortened` AS `shortened_degree`, `ai`.`name` AS `area_name`, `ed`.`name` AS `building_name` 
FROM `events` `e` 
LEFT JOIN `event_schedule` `eh` ON `e`.`id` = `eh`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `event_degree` `ec` ON `e`.`id` = `ec`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `degree` `c` ON `c`.`id` = `ec`.`degree_id` 
LEFT JOIN `event_area` `ea` ON `e`.`id` = `ea`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `area` `ai` ON `ai`.`id` = `ea`.`area_id` 
LEFT JOIN `building` `ed` ON `ed`.`id` = `ai`.`building_id` 
WHERE `e`.`active` = '1' 
AND `eh`.`start_date` >= '2016-03-08' 
AND `eh`.`end_date` < '2016-07-01' 
ORDER BY `eh`.`fecha_inicio` ASC;
```

and as a result i get all the rows "duplicated" as you can see in the picture

[image: picture]

how can i avoid this, thanks for your help

** note **
it's the same event so it should be displaying only 1 row for every event the problem is that i has 3 many to many relationships
so the things that change are only dates, degrees and areas

Comment: Distinct / group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY

```
SELECT DISTINCT `e`.*, `eh`.`start_date`, `eh`.`end_date`, `c`.`name` AS `degree_name`, `c`.`shortened` AS `shortened_degree`, `ai`.`name` AS `area_name`, `ed`.`name` AS `building_name` 
FROM `events` `e` 
LEFT JOIN `event_schedule` `eh` ON `e`.`id` = `eh`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `event_degree` `ec` ON `e`.`id` = `ec`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `degree` `c` ON `c`.`id` = `ec`.`degree_id` 
LEFT JOIN `event_area` `ea` ON `e`.`id` = `ea`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `area` `ai` ON `ai`.`id` = `ea`.`area_id` 
LEFT JOIN `building` `ed` ON `ed`.`id` = `ai`.`building_id` 
WHERE `e`.`active` = '1' 
AND `eh`.`start_date` >= '2016-03-08' 
AND `eh`.`end_date` < '2016-07-01'
GROUP BY `your_id`;
```

Comment: Thanks! for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` while selecting

```
SELECT DISTINCT `e`.*, `eh`.`start_date`, `eh`.`end_date`, `c`.`name` AS `degree_name`, `c`.`shortened` AS `shortened_degree`, `ai`.`name` AS `area_name`, `ed`.`name` AS `building_name` 
FROM `events` `e` 
LEFT JOIN `event_schedule` `eh` ON `e`.`id` = `eh`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `event_degree` `ec` ON `e`.`id` = `ec`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `degree` `c` ON `c`.`id` = `ec`.`degree_id` 
LEFT JOIN `event_area` `ea` ON `e`.`id` = `ea`.`event_id` 
LEFT JOIN `area` `ai` ON `ai`.`id` = `ea`.`area_id` 
LEFT JOIN `building` `ed` ON `ed`.`id` = `ai`.`building_id` 
WHERE `e`.`active` = '1' 
AND `eh`.`start_date` >= '2016-03-08' 
AND `eh`.`end_date` < '2016-07-01' 
ORDER BY `eh`.`fecha_inicio` ASC;
```